# How to display button and div around a chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I'm a student pretty new to the javascript/css.

I'm trying to display button around a canvas.
And i would like to show some text behind the button when i mouseover them (for that i used div).

But i got difficultees with set the position of the div when they're supposed to be behind the button placed horizontaly.

**Here is pictures showing what is great : the button placed Verticaly ( mouseover over one of the verticaly button)**

[[image: ) :]

**Here is pictures showing what I got / the issue (1 picture = 1 mouseover over one of the buttons**

[first Horizontal button is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eeOW.png)

[third Horizontal button is really not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRsEm.png)

And there it is my code :

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>crapmoni while waiting</title>
 </head>
 <body >

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>  <!-- Script pour les dates en vue js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./JQUERY/libs/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>  <!-- FONCTIONNE NORMALEMENT -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>





<div id="app"> <!--DIV CONTENANT NOTRE GRAPHIQUE-->
 <div class="container-fluid"> 

<div class="col-md-1" id="listeBtn2" style="width: 4.3333%" > <!--col md1 resizer a 4.33% -->

<button class="P2btnSite0 P2btnSite"><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax0 NameMax">CampingAtlantiqueFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite1 P2btnSite"><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax1 NameMax">ChadotelFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite2 P2btnSite" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax2 NameMax">CybeleVacancesFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite3 P2btnSite" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax3 NameMax">EurocampFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite4 P2btnSite" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax4 NameMax">HomairFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite5 P2btnSite" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax5 NameMax">MadameVacancesFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite6 P2btnSite" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax6 NameMax">MisterCampFlux</div>
<button class="P2btnSite7 P2btnSite" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
<div class="P2NameMax7 NameMax">PausadoFlux</div>


</div> <!--ferme le col md 1 -->

<div class="col-md-3" >  
<div class="card" id="Graphique1">

<button id="btnlineChart2" class="btnlineChart2"> <img src="./images/icons8-graphique-24.png"></button>
<button id="btnZoom2" class="btnZomm2"> <img src="./images/icons8-zoom-agrandir-25.png"></button>
<div id="smileyP2" class="smileyP2"></div> <!--permet d'y inserer une image grasse innerHttml-->
<canvas id="bar-chart-grouped2" class="HzBarChart2" height="400" >  </canvas>  
 </div> <!--ferme le card-->


 <button class="test P1btnSite00"><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
 <button class="test P1btnSite01"><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
 <button class="test P1btnSite02" ><img src="./images/icons8-histogramme-25.png"> </button>
 <div class="P1NameMax00 NameMax">data1</div>
 <div class="P1NameMax01 NameMax">data2</div>
 <div class="P1NameMax02 NameMax">data3</div>



</div> <!--ferme le col md 3 -->

</div>

</div> <!--**********close app !! ************-->

 </body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
button.test{

 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}


div.NameMax     
{
visibility: hidden;
}

/* Button which are placed horizontaly to the canvas*/
button.P1btnSite00:hover ~ div.P1NameMax00{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P1btnSite00:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}

button.P1btnSite01:hover ~ div.P1NameMax01{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P1btnSite01:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}

div.P1NameMax01{
 margin-left: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
}

button.P1btnSite02:hover ~ div.P1NameMax02{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P1btnSite02:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}

div.P1NameMax02{
 margin-left: 140px;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
}

/* Button which are placed verticaly to the canvas*/

button.P2btnSite0:hover ~ div.P2NameMax0{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite0:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite1:hover ~ div.P2NameMax1{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite1:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite2:hover ~ div.P2NameMax2{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite2:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite3:hover ~ div.P2NameMax3{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite3:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite4:hover ~ div.P2NameMax4{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite4:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite5:hover ~ div.P2NameMax5{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite5:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite6:hover ~ div.P2NameMax6{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite6:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}


button.P2btnSite7:hover ~ div.P2NameMax7{
 visibility: visible;
}
.P2btnSite7:hover{background-color:#5cbf2a;}
```

Comment: Your screenshot is not clear (Very small) + The Q (Maybe add flow screenshots). Anyway, create GUI & complex data change by clicks is not for newbies to javascript (Start first from simple chart.js examples) + Add snippet (Not copy-paste md code) - https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hello, welcome back to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to properly ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems you already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614441/trying-to-display-button-and-div-around-my-chart). If you want to add informations or clarify your question, please use the **edit** function instead of reposting the same question.

Comment: @EzraSiton thank you for your quick answer. I updated the pictures. I said i was a beginner but I got some skills in js (i've been workin on it since 5 months).  I know that my chart isn't displaying anything but that's not the purpose right here (I already know how to use chart.js very well. Moreover my buttons are supposed to do nothing when i clicked on them. There is only an action that show my div when i MouseOver them) Here it's a problem about css or maybe Bootstrap :)